# Load Balancer for LDAP(S)

Tags: load-balancing, ldap, freeipa, 389-ds, ldapsearch

I have created a load balancer in the cloud with backend servers running FreeIPA.
When I try to run:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap:<IP-ADDRESS> -b "dc=example,dc=com
ldap_sasl_bind(SIMPLE): Can't contact LDAP server (-1)
```

However, it's possible to contact each of the server:

```
$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap:<NODE1-ADDRESS> -b "dc=example,dc=com
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
...

$ ldapsearch -x -H ldap:<NODE2-ADDRESS> -b "dc=example,dc=com
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
...
```

In theory, shouldn't I be able to run the command `ldapsearch -x -H ldap:<IP-ADDRESS> -b "dc=example,dc=com`?

**EDIT: What LB configuration has been done from my side**
The servers and the load balancer can be found in the same subnet

**Security Rules (Traffic allowed)**
Ingress: 22, 53, 80, 88, 389, 636, 443
Egress: All

**Backend/Backend sets:**

- Server: Node1 Port: 389
- Server: Node2 Port: 389
- Server: Node1 Port: 636
- Server: Node2 Port: 636

**Listeners**

- Server: Node1 Port: 389
- Server: Node2 Port: 389
- Server: Node1 Port: 636
- Server: Node2 Port: 636

**Health checks:**

- Health checking TCP port 389/636.

Comment: That error  suggests that your load balancer is not configured with  (correct) rules to accept incoming  LDAP traffic and load balance it correctly AND/OR your load balancing method may require on additional configuration of the back-end servers

Comment: Thanks @HBrujin.
The load balancer accepts the same incoming traffic as the two nodes. I've open both ldap and ldaps using protocol TCP.

Comment: And yet when contacting your   *"load balancer in the cloud"*  you get a `Can't contact LDAP server` error message. From our side of the question we can't see what you're doing right, doing wrong or missing. Please add sufficient details:  What load balancing mechanism did you configure for the LDAP traffic/port(s) , what rules,  is there a (successful)  health check involved for the back end servers etc. etc. etc. Just opening port 389 on a loadbalancer does  not make it load balance LDAP traffic. (which is what your comment suggests as the only thing you did.)

Comment: So... There's security rules that allow ingress traffic to port 389/636 etc. I've created healthchecks to the backends servers specifically on the LDAP/LDAPS ports, which reports back "Healthy". However, I'm still you're right from your first commen, since I tried to make a similar backend/backend set for SSH connection (just for test), which doesn't seem to work, either.

Comment: Depending on the load balancer, in addition to a back-end you also need a  front end / listener / ingress definition on the load balancer and  link the LDAP port(s) on the load balancer  to those back-ends

Comment: @HBruijn, I appreciate your comments. I'll go back to the drawing board to see what I did wrong. This is a NLB in OCI.

Comment: @HBruijn, I tried to create a new similar network load balancer turning off the option: `is_preserve_source_destination`, meaning setting it to `false`. I was then able to access my backends. Any reason for this?